# Exception Oracle Instead of Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hello i'm new with Oracle Databases and test some Functions. Now i have Problems with Instead of triggers.

This is my code:

```
    CREATE TABLE team(
    teamid integer PRIMARY KEY,
    team VARCHAR2(100)
);


CREATE TABLE player(
    playerid integer PRIMARY KEY,
    player VARCHAR2(100),
    position VARCHAR2(100),
    teamid integer REFERENCES team(teamid)
);


INSERT ALL
  INTO team (teamid, team) VALUES (1, 'FC Bayern Muenchen')
  INTO team (teamid, team) VALUES (2, 'Manchester United')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;


INSERT ALL
  INTO player (playerid, player, position, teamid) VALUES (1, 'Manuel Neuer', 'goalkeeper', 1)
  INTO player (playerid, player, position, teamid) VALUES (2, 'Dante', 'defense', 1)
  INTO player (playerid, player, position, teamid) VALUES (3, 'Cesc Fabregas', 'midfield', 2)
  INTO player (playerid, player, position, teamid) VALUES (4, 'Lionel Messi', 'striker', 2)
  INTO player (playerid, player, position, teamid) VALUES (5, 'Arjen Robben', 'midfield', 1)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;


CREATE VIEW view_player AS
SELECT p.playerid,p.player,p.position, t.team FROM player p
INNER JOIN team t
ON  p.teamid = t.teamid;
```

I got a Sequence and Trigger for the Auto Increment of both Tables.
This is my Instead of Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER view_player_insert
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON view_player
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    NUMBER anzTeams;
    NUMBER teamID;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO anzTeams FROM team WHERE team=:NEW.team;
    IF anzTeams > 0
    THEN
        INSERT INTO team(team) VALUES (:NEW.team);
    END IF;

    SELECT teamid INTO teamID FROM team WHERE team=:NEW.team;
    INSERT INTO player(player,position,fbid) VALUES (:NEW.player,:NEW.position,teamID);
END;
```

I got this Exception with my Instead of Trigger:

> Exception in row 12: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I think i have an Syntax error, but i don't know who. I hope you can help me :)

Greetz Ulti

Answer (score 0):

More a comment (can't comment, pun intended).

- I didn't know that you could have same columns and table names.
- In declaration clause order of variable name and type can be
  interchanged. In last statement change fbid with teamID. With these
  two changes, the trigger compiles. I did not get any error on line
  12.

Comment: Ah thanks now i didn't get any error, too. but if i make a new insert i got these exception :/ 

ORA-01422: Exakter Abruf gibt mehr als die angeforderte Zeilenzahl zurück
ORA-06512: in "SYSTEM.VIEW_PLAYER_INSERT", Zeile 11
ORA-04088: Fehler bei der Ausführung von Trigger 'SYSTEM.VIEW_PLAYER_INSERT'

Comment: I think you want to do   IF anzTeams = 0 and not   IF anzTeams > 0.

Comment: i have one more question. I write a new answer for it in this thread. Perhaps you can help me with this second problem :)